# Dynamically change the template depend on screen orientation ionic v1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am working on ionic 1 project. I want to change the template according to screen orientation like:

```
 if(portrait) 
  // template 1
else 
 // template 2
```

I tried below code:

```
//detect orientation here
function weAreOnPortrait() {
    return true
};
$stateProvider.state({
  templateUrl: function () {
    if (weAreOnPortrait()) {return 'tmpl/feature/_portrait.html'}
    else {return 'tmpl/feature/_landscape.html'}
  },
  controller: 'CommonControllerForBothCases'
});
```

But this is running only once. I want to run every time the orientation changes.

How can I manage this?

I am able to get the orientation using https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite your route-definition a little bit, use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to execute your desired template-url for `templateUrl` depending on your screen-orientation:

```
function weAreOnPortrait() {
    return screen.orientation.type && screen.orientation.type.indexOf('portrait') !== -1
}

$stateProvider.state({
  templateUrl: (function () {
    if (weAreOnPortrait()) {return 'tmpl/feature/_portrait.html'}
    else {return 'tmpl/feature/_landscape.html'}
  })(),
  controller: 'CommonControllerForBothCases'
});
```

And you need a listener to screen-orientation changes to reload the page if a change has been detected:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){

    // if a change was detected reload page again by using transitionTo
    $state.transitionTo($state.current, {
            reload: true
    });

    // or by using go
    $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});

    // or by using location
    location.reload(true)

});
```

Although I could not test it, this should work.

Hope it helps.